# Add Search Bar to Table View

Tags: swift, search, swift3, tableview, uisearchbar

I am new to swift and I was wondering how to add a Search bar to the table view where it filters the table view and whenever a user clicks on the cell, it opens the view controller it is designed to open.

Please keep in mind that I made my table view and all the cells in in in the main.storyboard, so they are not coded.

Like I said, I am 100% new to coding, so please try to make it as easy as possible! Thanks! :)

*iOS app using Swift 3 and Xcode 8*

Comment: Try this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial, then come back here when you have specific problems

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm in a similar boat. EVERY tutorial I have found uses a table view controller not a table view. I need to add this search piece to a pre existing controller so I can't go the table view controller route

Answer (score 0):

Make a searchbar with:

```
 lazy var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20))
```

Add Delegates to your class:

```
UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate
```

Implement Methods like:

```
searchBarTextDidBeginEditing , searchBarTextDidEndEditing , searchBarCancelButtonClicked , searchBarSearchButtonClicked
```

and of course don't forget

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
}
```

then you can start putting a check in your *cellForRowAt* method for the *tableview* to check whether  you are searching or not and update your list.

But this is pretty advanced for someone who is 100% new to coding, would recommend starting with something easier.

My class that achieves this is about 500 lines of code.